# Allocate memory from Windows to Linux partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, gparted

I found out I can do that with `gparted`, but I am just wondering, in my case, how to act and what steps to take, because the partitions situation is messy:

[image: screenshot]

So, `sda1` and `sda2` are the system reserve for Windows and the `C drive`, respectively. The `sda3` is the `D drive`, which I use for personal data and I use it from both Win and Ubuntu. And then follow the Linux drives.

The 30 GB of unallocated space, between `C` and `D`, I freed from the `C drive` and want to extend `sda6` with it (actually I want to do it with 70 GB in total, but these 30 GB were just for testing).

A friend told me that I can't allocate the free space to `sda6` because `sda3` stands in between. I am really unacknowledged in this situation, so I would like to ask for some help and more precisely - tips for what to do step by step. *Without the need of re-installing or completely formatting anything, please.*

Answer (score 1):

Without the need of re-installing or completely formatting anything, test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
    sudo -i
    umount /dev/sda3
    gparted
```

Since gparted add space unallocated to /dev/sda3 and apply the changes

You have added 30,54 Gib to /dev/sda3

Close gparted and reboot, running on the terminal:

```
    reboot
```

If everything works correctly, do you think a file in free space from /dev/sda3 to use in Ubuntu.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
    sudo -i
    cd /media/milkncookiez/4C60D12760D11912
    dd if=/dev/zero of=part-ext count=31457280
    mkfs.ext3 /media/milkncookiez/4C60D12760D11912/part-ext
```

From now on, you have available a file of 30GB space to mount as ext3 in Ubuntu.

Assuming you want to mount it as /data in your /home/user directory, you must:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
     sudo -i
     mkdir /home/milkncookiez/data
     mount -o loop /media/milkncookiez/4C60D12760D11912/part-ext /home/milkncookiez/data
     chmod -Rf 777 /home/milkncookiez/data
```

And you have available a 30GB in /home/milkncookiez/data.

To make the changes permanent, you must:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
     sudo -i
     nano /etc/fstab
```

You should add this line to the end of file:

```
   /media/milkncookiez/4C60D12760D11912/part-ext  /home/milkncookiez/data  ext3 loop,rw,auto  0   2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.