# Increase Ubuntu disk space

Tags: partitioning

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot. I have allocated 15Gb of free space (shrank the Windows partition) which I'd like to add to my Ubuntu partition. So now it's allocated like this: `Windows - 15 Gb of unallocated space - Ubuntu`. I run Ubuntu from Live USB and launch gparted to try to merge that unallocated space to my Ubuntu partition but I get a message that says:

> You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition
>   /dev/sda5.  Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the
>   GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows
>   system partition C:. You can learn how to repair the boot
>   configuration in the GParted FAQ. http://gparted.org/faq.php
>
> Moving a partition might take a very long time to apply.

So, uh, is there a way to somehow avoid meddling with GRUB and add that free space to my current partition? If no, then will just following the instructions from the provided FAQ be enough for everything to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add more disk space for linux from windows in a dual bootable machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871825/add-more-disk-space-for-linux-from-windows-in-a-dual-bootable-machine) Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/852395/re-allocate-partition-space-from-windows-to-linux and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/727112/give-more-hard-disk-space-to-ubuntu and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/502781/how-to-give-ubuntu-14-04-more-disk-space

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've seen this question and I did the same thing that was explained there. An attempt to perform `resize/move` led me to the warning message I've posted in my question. The question you are referring to does not provide an answer to mine, so I created this one. I don't think it can be considered as a duplicate.

Comment: Can you try the three other links I posted as well? These are only some of the duplicates here in **Ask Ubuntu**. Google search will reveal additional hits using *"Increase Ubuntu and reduce Windows size"* or something similar. Are you using **UEFI**? I'm not sure if the duplicate candidates address this specifically.

Comment: GRUB will be fine, you can proceed with moving the partition ( though it will take a long time and a power failure or crash will trash all of your data, so make a backup first ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give more Hard disk space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727112/give-more-hard-disk-space-to-ubuntu)