# Allocate free memory from Windows to Linux partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

[image]

I want to add the unallocated memory to my Ubuntu partition on `/dev/sda7` Without the need of re-installing or completely formatting anything, please.
my problem is quite similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545329/allocate-memory-from-windows-to-linux-partition) but I couldn't solve it this way. Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to resize a running root partition, although it can in some cases be done.  Easier, burn a liveUSB, boot from that device and use `gparted` from the liveUSB to resize your  'dev/sda7' into the unallocated space.

Comment: That is not memory, it is disc space. The free space must be adjacent to the partition you wist to enlarge, so you have to move the partitions one a a time.

Comment: It worked with the live CD. It was more simpler as expected. Thank you very much